# for loop multiplication program does not output properly

Tags: java

Now ive run into another issue with loops, this time trying to make a simple multiplication program using the same code as above.

```
    package loops;


import java.util.Scanner;

 public class forloops {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer you wish to multiply");

    int loopval;
    int end_val = 11;
    int times = input.nextInt();


    for (loopval = 0; loopval < end_val; loopval++) {
        times = times * loopval;
        System.out.println(loopval + " " +"Times" + " " + times + " " + "=");

}




    }
}
```

My output loops from 1 - 10, but it seems to just exponetiate. I am just trying to make it go 1 times 5 = 5, 2 times 5 = 10, etc.

Comment: This is a logic error, and not really a programming question: Think about what the value of `times` is each time through your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this;

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer you wish to multiply");

    int loopval;
    int end_val = 11;
    int value = input.nextInt();


    for (loopval = 0; loopval < end_val; loopval++) {
        int result = value * loopval;
        System.out.println(loopval + " " +"Times" + " " + value + " " + "=" + result);

}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I forgot to add another variable. This makes much more sense.